# How are my multiplayer opponents placing multiple girders in one turn?

Tags: ios, worms-2007

When I'm playing against someone on my iPhone I've come across people that can place multiple girders on one turn. How the heck are they doing that? I've tried doing that in practice nose and for the life of me I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 4):

"Girder Starter Pack" was a thing back in Worms Armageddon.

In the newer Worms games it's called the "Bridge Kit". It lets you place five girders. It's a seperate weapon.